Is it possible to make an viable build centered around handle animal?
So, part two to a question I asked regarding how to make a horse viable, I decided to try going with Plan B and wondered if there was any way to make a build centered around handle animal. On one hand, it looks like something that could be used to get your own animal army.
On the other hand, since none of these animals scale, you'd be hard pressed to use most of them in a way that doesn't result in them dying in one hit.
So what can we do?
The general idea I'm thinking of is an Animal Tamer/Ranch hand who is just naturally gifted with communicating with animals, who can raise and lead them into doing all sorts of different things.

There's a few different questions hiding in here and I'm not sure what you're looking for an answer to. Right now I see, "Is it possible to make a build centered around handle animal?"; "How can I make my own personal animal army?"; "How can I make an army of animals scale up?"; and a general question of, "What can we do?" I think you need to provide additional details regarding what you're trying to do and provide any supporting info on what you've looked at thus far.

Yes, it is possible to make a build centered around handle animal. The question you should be asking is "How can I make an effective build centered around handle animal?". I'm voting to close for now; if you edit this to be more focused, it might be answerable.

Please to not signal edits in the text of your question if you edit it. Thank you.  You have  been around this site long enough to know that.
